# Full Outer Join, Coalesce, and Group By (Oh My!)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, coalesce, full-outer-join

I'm going to ask this in two parts, because my logic may be way off, and if so, the syntax doesn't really matter.

1. I have 10 queries.  Each query returns month, supplier, and count(*some metric*).  The queries use various tables, joins, etc.  Not all month/supplier combinations exist in the output for each query.  I would like to combine these into a single data set that can be exported and pivoted on in Excel.

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
Month | Supplier | Metric1 |Metric2 |..| Metric 10
2018-01 | Supp1 | _value_ | _value_ |...| _value_ |
2018-01 | Supp2 | NULL | _value_ |...| NULL
```

What is the best / easiest / most efficient way to accomplish this?

2. I've tried various methods to accomplish the above, but I can't seem to get the syntax quite right.  I wanted to make a very simple test case and build upon it, but I only have select privileges on the db, so I am unable to test it out.  I was able to create a query that at least doesn't result in any squiggly red error lines, but applying the same logic to the bigger problem doesn't work.

This is what I've got:

```
 create table test1(name varchar(20),credit int);
 insert into test1 (name, credit) values ('Ed',1),('Ann',1),('Jim',1),('Ed',1),('Ann',1);
 create table test2 (name varchar(10), debit int);
 insert into test2 (name, debit) values ('Ann',1),('Sue',1),('Sue',1),('Sue',1);

 select
    coalesce(a.name, b.name) as name,
    cred,
    deb
 from
    (select name, count(credit) as cred
        from test1 
        group by name) a
    full outer join 
    (select name, count(debit) as deb
        from test2
        group by name) b  on 
     a.name =b.name;
```

Am I headed down the right path?

UPDATE:  Based on Gordon's input, I tried this on the first two queries:

```
select Month, Supp,
    sum(case when which = 1 then metric end) as Exceptions,
    sum(case when which = 2 then metric end) as BackOrders
from (
        (
         select Month, Supp, metric, 1 as which
         from (
                select (convert(char(4),E.PostDateTime,120)+'-'+convert(char(2),E.PostDateTime,101)) as Month, E.TradingPartner as Supp, count(distinct(E.excNum)) as metric
                from db..TrexcMangr E
                where (E.DSHERep in ('AVR','BTB') OR E.ReleasedBy in ('AVR','BTB')) AND year(E.PostDateTime) >= '2018'
              ) a
         )

         union all

        (
         select Month, Supp, metric, 2 as which
         from (
                select (convert(char(4),T.UpdatedDateTime,120)+'-'+convert(char(2),T.UpdatedDateTime,101)) as Month, P.Supplier as Supp, count(*) as metric
                from db1..trordertext T
                    inner join mdid_Tran..trOrderPO P on P.PONum = T.RefNum
                where T.TextType = 'BO' AND (T.CreatedBy in ('AVR','BTB') OR T.UpdatedBy in ('AVR','BTB')) AND year(UpdatedDateTime) >=2018
              ) b
        )
     ) q
group by Month, Supp
```

... but I'm getting a group by error.

Comment: It would be helpful to see that full, exact, actual, error.

Comment: Also, try not to use the column name `Month`.  It causes confusion due to the existence of a a `MONTH()` function.  You could use `[Month]`, but it's better in normal practice to avoid using existing keywords as column names; perhaps use `sMonth` as you're manipulating everything as a string?  *(That said, using strings to manipulate and represent dates is a generally bad idea.)*

Comment: Are you deliberately not including a `GROUP BY` in your sub-queries?  That looks like an error to me...

Comment: What is the `group by` error?

Comment: If you add a aggregate function like a `count(*)`  then you also need to GROUP BY on the columns you select. (if not used in an aggregate function)

Comment: Here's the error I'm getting: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 56
Column 'db.TrexcMangr.PostDateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  Let me try putting a group by back into the subqueries.

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] and [mcve]. Don't just say you got an error, give the error message & code we can cut & paste & run ourselves. And read the manual re the problem language syntax & error, and google them with & without your particular names/strings. Please do not clarify via comments, edit your post to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `union all` and `group by`:

```
select month, supplier,
       sum(case when which = 1 then metric end) as metric_01,
       sum(case when which = 2 then metric end) as metric_02,
       . . .
from ((select Month, Supplier, Metric, 1 as which
       from (<query1>) q
       . . .
      ) union all
      (select Month, Supplier, Metric, 2 as which
       from (<query2>) q
       . . .
      ) union all
      . . .
     ) q
group by month, supplier;
```

Comment: I think I may have oversimplified the problem.  The month and supplier columns aren't always called the same thing in every table.  I tried your suggestion on the first two queries, but I'm getting a group by error.

Comment: @sandeaj - That shouldn't matter.  Use aliases to "rename" the columns to standarised column names...  `(SELECT mmm AS month, Supp AS supplier, Metric, 1 AS which FROM source1)`  *(Assumes that the columns have the same datatype, formatting, etc, just different names...)*

Comment: When using a union, only the names of the first query matter. The seconded unioned query doesn't even have to have names. But it does need to return the same data types in the same order as the first query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CalendarMonthStart,
    Supp,
    SUM(CASE WHEN metric_id = 1 THEN metric END) as Exceptions,
    SUM(CASE WHEN metric_id = 2 THEN metric END) as BackOrders
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, E.PostDateTime), 0)   AS CalendarMonthStart,
        E.TradingPartner            AS Supp,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(E.excNum))   AS metric,
        1                           AS metric_id
    FROM
        db..TrexcMangr E
    WHERE
        (      E.DSHERep    in ('AVR','BTB')
            OR E.ReleasedBy in ('AVR','BTB')
        )
        AND E.PostDateTime >= '2018-01-01'
    GROUP BY
        1, 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, T.UpdatedDateTime), 0)   AS CalendarMonthStart,
        T.UpdatedDateTime,
        P.Supplier                  AS Supp,
        COUNT(*)                    AS metric,
        2                           AS metric_id
    FROM
        db1..trordertext T
    INNER JOIN
        mdid_Tran..trOrderPO P
            ON  P.PONum = T.RefNum
    WHERE
        (      T.CreatedBy in ('AVR','BTB')
            OR T.UpdatedBy in ('AVR','BTB')
        )
        AND T.TextType = 'BO'
        AND T.UpdatedDateTime >= '2018-01-01'
    GROUP BY
        1, 2
)
   combined
GROUP BY
    CalendarMonthStart,
    Supp
```